# Are the Nazi Party, Communist Party, and Bolsheviks far-right or far-left?

Tags: political-history

I am really confused why some or all of these parties are considered to be far-right and not far-left. They are mostly socialist parties which took the ideology too far. What are the academic criteria to determine where a party/dictatorship is on the right-left spectrum?

Comment: Who *doesn't* consider Communists or Bolsheviks far-left?

Comment: Fascist and communist parties are the ones that give the meaning of "far-right" and "far-left", and I see no other meaning such terms may have except in relation to these parties.

Comment: Can you specify what e.g. [Political Spectrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Political_spectrum) does not answer to your satisfaction?

Comment: There *is* a saying that "the political spectrum is a circle" (e.g. by Franz Müntefering). This is to say that, in addition to the left - right spectrum (egalitarian - elitist, internationalist - nationalist, progressive - conservative etc.), there is also a spectrum of democratic vs. radical, with the "moderate" parties on the one end and both the far-right *and* the far-left on the other. But the Nazis were **not** socialists, they were *very much* about an authoritarian state, and class (race) privilege. It's just that certain methods of the far-left and far-right are similar.

Comment: Ideology is all about power, not principles. Trying to classify ideologies is pointless. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Politics_and_the_English_Language

Comment: This isn't a question about history (the persistent use of the present tense is a dead giveaway). Typically I'd suggest moving it to the Politics site, but given the current fad in the US of pretending exactly this confusion as a backhanded political attack, I suspect they've answered this many times before.

Comment: @T.E.D., I was thinking to phrase `was the ....`, but I figured out the parties' affiliation on the spectrum was given to them only now.

Comment: The idea that national socialism was **not** a socialist party is not correct. Many of the social laws introduced during that time were retained in both in east and west Germany. Health insurance for all being one, work conditions another. Nationalization was part of the party program until February 1933. The needs of the community overrides the needs of the individual was the core of their ideology and was practiced until the end. Other than who can belong to the community (national/race or international) both left and right are similar. The circle idea is more realistic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are asking as if those terms had a clear scientific or at least philosophical meaning. They are ideological, polemical, and sometimes superficial terms.

What left and right means in politics is complicated and it may vary depending on the country and context.

Already the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left%E2%80%93right_political_spectrum) mentions this complexity.

Being vague doesn't stop them being used anyway in real life, mostly in journalistic, electoral, or other contradictory arguments, but cannot be used in a serious philosophical argument, and no scientific significance  can be ascribed to them. They have been created for the purpose of political debate, a purpose that is in many cases propagandistic and polemic, not descriptive or explanatory.

Their meaning is created on a "spectrum" based on opposition between parties in relation to fundamental values, ideals and institutions. These values, ideals, institutions that represent the "apple of discord" may vary depending on the historical context, and thus the meaning of these terms also varies.

There are many partially different "spectrums" where these terms take somewhat different meaning according to the object of discord:

- **Monarchy**: the **[original](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left%E2%80%93right_political_spectrum#History_of_the_terms) French** meaning, in relation to the faith of French monarchy: left being anti-monarchical or republican, right being pro-monarchical; that meaning is still partially present in French politics but was largely replaced by the others;
- **Socialism**: the meaning in relation to the socialist movement and the "class-struggle" concept, the history of **capitalism** and socialism and the recent pro-capitalist reforms in the ex-communist states; this is the meaning that is mostly present in Europe, where "right" means "pro-capitalist" or in favor of free enterprise, and "left" means in favor of economically disadvantaged people;
- **Nationalism**: where patriotism and national identity is exalted by the "right" in opposition to its adversaries ("left") for whom this is not the main concern.
- **Democracy**: when democracy is at stake or under attack, its adversaries will impose the meaning of "right" and "left": the far-right will consider the democrats being "left", the far-left will consider them as "right".

It is obvious that other topics may create different "spectrums", some of them outdated (colonialism) and some new (ecology), but what is certain is that "right" and "left" have different meaning in the different "spectrums", the same party or opinion may have *different* qualities (*right* or *left*) depending on the spectrum, but also they may have *the same* quality in different "spectrums" without these qualities having the same meaning.

The main complication comes from the fact that these "spectrums" are superposed for practical or ideological reasons but in many cases without the full awareness of those involved in the debate; thus the meaning of our terms become confusing, even contradictory.

Things get more complicated by the fact that in time certain elements or institutions that were present (and determined the meaning of these terms) fade away or, on the contrary, they stop being subject of debate and are taken for granted. 
For example, monarchy is no more a subject of debate in France. Democracy is not a subject of debate in many democracies, like the United States, Australia, New Zealand or in parts of Europe (where no party promotes dictatorship); in such countries "right" and "left" take their meaning from other "apples of discord".

In some cases other basic terms have different meaning based on the context; in the US "liberal" and "left" mean almost the same thing, close to "socialist", while in Europe "liberal" is used in relation to political and economic *Liberalism*.

---

In order to directly answer the question: the Nazi party and the Italian Fascist party can be considered far-right, the Russian Bolshevik and all real-Communist parties ("real" as in *Realpolitik*) can be considered far-left in most of the theoretical "spectrums" described above.

If you are also talking about the more or less *democratic* communist parties or factions (in the sense of the "democracy as we know it", not in that of the "popular" democracies; I will not touch the problem of how "democracy" can mean "dictatorship" in real-Communism) then there's a different matter, as those cannot be then seen as "far-left" or "extreme", but come closer to the West-European socialism and Social-Democracy. (Your question *is* vague, simplistic, and about to be closed for good reasons.)

You seem to wonder whether the two categories of parties could be placed within the same area of any of the "political spectrums". Could they? Surely not in the cases I mentioned.

The only case imaginable would be one in which they had common goals and a common adversary, and that would be the rejection of democracy "as we know it" (liberal, "bourgeois") in favor of an authoritarian project. But there, as I said, as they impose the extreme meaning of "right" and "left", these "extreme" parties are at opposite ends of the spectrum (with the democrats at the center). 
While socialism vs capitalism, republic vs monarchy,  and internationalism vs nationalism can be described as a left-right definition of various types of a political spectrums, democracy vs authoritarianism has not produced *in reality* a such spectrum in which fascist/nazis and bolshevik/communist would be at the *same* extreme of the spectrum. Even then, each of these extremist parties would give opposite descriptions of their own position. A democrat could be imagined putting them side by side at one extreme, but it is difficult to say if that far-region of the spectrum should then be called *right* or *left*, or whether these terms keep their meaning in a such case.

As right and left serve mostly propagandistic and polemic purposes in real political adversity, the parties that are most aggressive ideologically tend to impose the most pervasive meaning of these terms, given that the ideologies of such parties need clear and categorical, even simplistic and one-sided terminology. But in order for a such discussion to even have a meaning such parties have to be present within the same spectrum. They can do that only theoretically, and, as I have said, these terms have a poor theoretical value; in reality both the Nazi and the Bolshevik (and other Communist parties of the "real socialism") had as main concern the fast resolution of the debate through the physical elimination of their political adversaries - and of *any* political diversity in fact. After that, the use of terms like *right and left* becomes useless or changes completely its meaning, like in the case of the persecution, prosecution and extermination by Stalin of his (real) "[left](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_Opposition)" and (imaginary) "right" opposition (the ["danger from the right"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Stalin#Dekulakisation,_collectivisation,_and_industrialisation:_1927%E2%80%931931)) *within* the Communist party.

Comment: No. "physical elimination of their adversaries" is not the over arching goal or effect of those 'communists'. Under Lenin & Stalin in the cultural revolution or Brother No1 systems it may resemble such, but most of the time re-education and submission was 'the option' offered. Something the Nazis did not ever offer Jews, (Lenin's henchmen didn't offer Nikolas), but Mao offered Pu Yi. In short: the force aspect is toned down in 'democracy' played up in 'communism' but overwhelming and eliminatory in fascism.

Comment: @LangLangC - "No"? - There is clearly a way to identify the most extremist parties by the fact they would prefer to eliminate all opposition, no matter if  through violent or pacifist means. But the latter cannot be taken seriously. Also, I am referring to political adversaries and opposition, and mainly to organized forms, that is parties or factions within the one party.

Comment: @LangLangC -  The degree of tolerance towards such forms of opposition was zero, and not only the effects were exterminatory, but also the intention, as terror was part of what you call "education". I had the "chance" myself to live under one of the "best" of such educative regimes where terror had played its role efficiently enough in the '50-s so that in the '80-s blood was rarely shed. Terrorist education continued, but the element of terror became invisible.

Comment: @LangLangC - Your comparison to the fate of the Jews is surprising (to put it mildly): they were not persecuted as *political* adversaries. One can alway *imagine* (I was about to say *"hope"*) that those that didn't immediately fall victims to the Hitlerian "racial bias" had a chance of redeeming themselves through "education". - And, by the way, *education* (as [re-education](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re-education_in_Communist_Romania)) is one of the most aggressive terms I know in the real-Communist propaganda.

Comment: @LangLangC - I see you put 'communists' in quotes, by the way, as if they were not "real", or "true", when in fact it is them who (from Lenin to the Kim dynasty) were (are) both the realist and real communists, by contrast to the "imaginary" ones.

Comment: I put marks around the labels to show that they are not always indicating what the amphora contains. https://www.npr.org/2018/11/21/669509554/in-china-the-communist-partys-latest-unlikely-target-young-marxists // NHS and Obamacare being called 'socialist' etc. Why not change "physical elimination" into (extreme) suppression? That word choice is just not good.

Comment: @LangLangC - Interesting, but I do not see that as counter-argument to my post not am I sure you have post it as such. Books by Marx were not available in European ex-communist countries before the fall of communism for the same reason the Bible was not accessible to common Christians during the Middle Ages. That doesn't make the Middle Ages and the Catholic Church at that time less Christian or "biblical", except for people ("real Christians") involved in a religious dispute on the matter (a Lutheran of the same era).

Comment: @LangLangC -  I guess the dispute whether "Marxian" or "Marxist" can be used or not with the same meaning as "Communist", or whether "Socialist" and "Communist" can be equated, is open, but (just as for your comment saying to change `physical elimination" into (extreme) suppression`), the question mentions the real historical nazis and communists, and I am talking about *them*. And in that case communists did intend to and did exterminate their political adversaries, and even *invented* them in order to keep the terror system going.

Comment: Now that's bull. [MEW alone was *sold* 3.5 million times](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marx-Engels-Werke) and then there were other editions, books, texts, often shortened to suit the party line, sometimes quite twisted, etc. Also  there is [MEGA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marx-Engels-Gesamtausgabe)

Comment: @LangLangC - `often shortened to suit the party line, sometimes quite twisted, etc`. I was saying that for the sake of argument, namely that your links rather confirms what I say. Not only opposition and dissent, but any debate, Marxian or not, is not tolerated under such regimes, and full access to Marx is *bound* to create debate. The degree of access to proper texts varied between countries but in USSR (and Romania) that was limited to universities under strict "guidance". You should not imagine entering a book shop and asking for Marx! - and - `bull` - please watch your language.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88737/discussion-between-langlangc-and-cipricus).

Comment: @LangLangC - chatting was indeed very pleasant, all above contention levelled out :)